# Nodejs in memory message bus using EventEmitter for cross modules communication

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

im new to nodejs, and I am looking for ways to have a pub/sub messaging in my node application that I can use for communication between module/packages.

Was looking into using EventEmitter maybe using the eventEmitter instance on the process so it can act as a global event bus. But I just have a bad feeling about doing that, I don't know node enough to come up with a solid reason to not doing that.

or is there an alternative approach?

this is only in memory not cross multiple instance

Comment: I would use the process object to subscribe (.on) and publish (.emit) events.

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on the module cache if you like. Some modules do that to maintain state if needed (e.g. mongoose).

So what I mean by that is if your message bus module maintains its state internally, and exports the pub/sub functions only, then any other module that requires it will get the same 'instance' and therefore be able to pub/sub against the same channel.

Comment: yeah that would work, but how does node's module cache works? do we still get the same instance if there are multiple versions of the "Custom Event" module used across multiple dependent modules?

Comment: More details here: http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/ but basically the cache is valid across the application.  If you're talking actual *versions*, (e.g. 1.2 vs 1.3) then no it won't be the same instance.  If you just mean you have several modules requiring it within your application, you should be fine.

Comment: I end up using gloabl to ensure we only have one instead of this event bus sort of.

Comment: you may want to look a "postal js " as a option.